# Configuring Webpack to work in a Laravel application

Tags: laravel, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to use **webpack-dev-server** for my basic Laravel application. From the [official Webpack docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) I learned the following:

> You may want to run a backend server or a mock of it in development.
>   You should not use the webpack-dev-server as a backend. Its only
>   purpose is to serve static (webpacked) assets.
>
> You can run two servers side-by-side: The webpack-dev-server and your
>   backend server.

At the bottom of the page they give an example on how to accomplish that. I followed along and got stuck with two error messages. This is my attempt to integrate Webpack into a Laravel application.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('resources'),
    entry: [
        './assets/js/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public/assets/'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/assets/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'public',
        hot: true,
        proxy: {
            "*": "http://laravel.dev/"
        }
    }
};
```

**app.blade.php**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Learning Laravel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    @yield('footer')
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/assets/bundle.js"/>
</body>

</html>
```

```
vagrant@learning-laravel:~/learning-laravel$ webpack-dev-server --inline
```

Console output:

```
http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from http://localhost:8080/assets/
content is served from public
Hash: 3346964212f5b22513c6
Version: webpack 1.12.2
Time: 347ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  228 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 213 kB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
    [1] /usr/lib/~/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 2.14 kB {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/url.js 22.3 kB {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
    [4] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] (webpack)/~/node-libs-browser/~/url/~/querystring/index.js 127
```

...

```
   [61] ./resources/assets/js/app.js 103 bytes {0} [built]
   [62] ./resources/assets/js/login.js 28 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'webpack/hot/dev-server' in /home/vagrant/learning-laravel/resources
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

I am using Homestead. The application is served on http://laravel.dev/. So my question is how to run the two servers (the webpack-dev-server and the backend-server) side by side. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it help if you completely remove `proxy` from `devServer`? I have pretty much the same setup and it works. Of course you can still use http://learning-laravel.dev:8888 or similar to access your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is simple, you have to proxy webpack-dev-server under the Laravel backend server (route /assets for example).

To do it, I let you check http-proxy, Express middlewares, and even socat / netcat CLI tools.